# How to install nvidia GeForce GT525M driver on Ubuntu12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome

I installed Ubuntu12.04 today and then I found my GeForce GT525M not being installed properly.It wasn't recognized by Ubuntu.But now I want to install GNOME3 and it requires my GT525M installed properly.So,what can I do to install my GT525M driver?Or how can I use GNOME3 normally?Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**I see you have a MOBILE graphics card on your computer, so I'd assumed you also have Intel Integrated graphics, and your graphics are hybrid switchable. Hope this helps!**

Below are instructions for restoring the elegant Unity 3D in your computer:

NOTE: Should work when you have a laptop fitted with MOBILE (GxxxM) Nvidia graphics card and has capability of switching graphics (ie. you have Intel Integrated graphics as well). This is a special case of graphics issue and must be handled differently.

Remove all nvidia drivers, install only x-swat PPAs (uses OpenGL and mesa-libs):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

or you can manually add in Update Manager settings, in the tab Other Software, type in the following APT line:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
```

Then, perform a list update and install the appropriate driver:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Remove all Nvidia drivers, install mesa-utils:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current nvidia-graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Type in the following line in terminal, if there's an error saying no GLX found in display, proceed

```
glxinfo
```

Reinstalling all components to refresh:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
```

Reset Unity (CLOSE AND SAVE EVERYTHING BEFORE DOING): (add sudo in front if superuser required)

```
unity --reset
```

Now wait till everything stabilises (even though your terminal window will go randomly on top and unmovable, no big deal), then (force?) relog in Ubuntu. You should see your perfect Unity 3D waiting for you.

> (Did I mention that this worked so well for me? Had exactly the same problem as you before, searched high and low for solutions that don't apply, finally went through this.)
>
> Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin 64bit, Geforce 310M with CUDA, Intel Core i5-460M.

Comment: Yes,I think I just have the problem you met.Thank you for your solution.And I want to know if this method works with gnome3.4?

Answer (score 0):

For installing Nvidia drivers, you can try the following at the ``terminal".

```
user$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If, as you said that, the drivers were not installed properly earlier, you can try:

```
user$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current
```

Please make sure that you are connected to the internet when you use these commands.