# HP Pavilion g6 1190sm laptop has overheat/hibernation/graphics issues

Tags: graphics, hp, overheating, hybrid-graphics

Every time I reboot or shutdown my laptop, while the laptop is booting again I get a screen (before loading the OS) that HP discovered overheating and system went into hibernation. But the point is that the laptop is not overheating nor going into hibernation by itself.

Also, because of the hybrid graphics card I cannot install additional drivers. Desktop resolution and all works perfectly but I cannot use Unity 3D. Also, OpenGL doesn't work as it should (with Cairo Dock).

As I've read some posts, people say that `vgaswitcheroo` doesn't work on 12.04 so I haven't tried it.

Comment: would you mind posting what graphics card?
and I have no clue why its saying its overheated or something

Comment: What model HP do you have?

Comment: Thanks for your replies ! CPU: intel i3, graphic: intel intergrated and radeon HD 6470m. It is HP Pavilion g6 1190sm (1190sm i belive is a model just in Slovenia. As I haven't noticed anywhere else (on google) that this model would be somewhere else in Europe or USA. It also might be good idea if I would update my BIOS as I have installed windows 7 back again.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Garphics?

This fixed the problem on my Dell Inspiron, you can try this:

(PS: Yes, I know you don't have a nVidia Graphic Card)

https://askubuntu.com/a/133302/66277

Comment: I have edited grub to force radeon graphics, uninstall all ati drivers, installed new, source drivers, which have compiled and built without a problem. At the end when I have genereted new Xorg config and service lightdm restart. I was unable to go back to desktop. When I have logged back it said that if I want to use low graphics settings, tty1-6