# what is the best nvidia driver version for NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

i installed NVIDIA drive auto install but when i restart, my screen will became black after that i have to go recovery mode and roll back earlier save then only my os ubutun 21.04 is working what to do.

any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score -2):

Great question.
I'll walk you through it!

Just copy/paste these into the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current nvidia-graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

After that, enter `glxinfo`. If it comes up with any errors, something went wrong. If not, continue to these steps!

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
```

**IMPORTANT: Close and save all important documents before this step!** 
Finally, put this in.

```
unity --reset
```

This should totally install the best drivers for your device. Do this at your own risk, you know more about your system than I do so make sure you check that this is what you want!

### Resources

- [How to install nvidia GeForce GT525M driver on Ubuntu12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132112/how-to-install-nvidia-geforce-gt525m-driver-on-ubuntu12-04)